# Is there an analogue to 'length' in time, in SR?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

It seems to me that the notion of 'length' (in 1 spatial dimension, I define the length of a body in a certain referential to be the maximal spatial gap of two of its points at the same time) has no analogue in time. That is, we don't have a name for the time that flow at a single point of space. So actually spatial contraction is not at all the 'spatial pendant' of time dilation. What we usually call spatial contraction is due both to the relativity of simultaneity and the gamma factor, but the gamma factor actually works against spatial contraction*. While time dilation is entirely due to the gamma factor and has nothing to do with relativity of space. Am I right? More generally, what other asymmetries are there between time and space in SR?

--

* If a ruler in a referential $R$ is at rest, let's say the left extremity is at $x=0$ at all times and the right one is at $x=\delta$ at all times. In the referential $R'$ moving at $u$ the left extremity has worldline $(\gamma ct,-\gamma u t)$ and the right one has worldline $(\gamma(ct-\beta \delta),\gamma(\delta - ut))$. If I inspect the length of my ruler in $R'$ at time $\gamma t_0$ ($\gamma$ factor for simplicity) , I will find the left extremity at $-\gamma u t_0$. For the right one, I have to solve $\gamma(ct-\beta \delta)=\gamma ct_0$ and then by plugging the result in my formula for the right extremity's worldline I get $\gamma (\delta - ut_0 - (u^2/c^2) \delta)$ and the difference gives $\delta/\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my Minkowski diagram, time and distances are very symmetric.
$R$ is black, $R'$ with $v=0.6c$ blue. You have clocks and rulers of unit length in both systems.
When you compare clocks in $R'$ from $R$ between 0 and 1s you see that the clock in $R'$ has not reached 1.
If you compare the ruler with your length 1  at time $t=0$ you see that the ruler in $R'$ is not 1, so it is completely symmetric. [image: Minkowsky diagram]